# In jqGrid, how to format timestamp to dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: jqgrid

My application send timestamp data to `jqgrid (like "1268913728759").`

now i want to format it like `dd/mm/yyyy`.

In `jqGrid` I added following line but it doesn't worked

```
{name:'testDate',index:'testDate', width:100, formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ts',newformat:'d/m/Y'}}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341824

Answer (score 7):

The correct seetings for this case should be like this:

```
formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'U', newformat:'d/m/Y'}
```

The 'U' is format character for 'Seconds since the Unix Epoch' date format.

Comment: Can you add some JSON to your question for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
formatter: function (cellValue, opts, rwd) {
    if (cellValue) {
        return $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", new Date(cellValue), opts, rwd);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

> The correct seetings for this case should be like this:
>
> ```
> formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'U', newformat:'d/m/Y'}
> ```
>
> The 'U' is format character for 'Seconds since the Unix Epoch' date
>   format.

The timestamp like "1268913728759" means milliseconds not seconds since the Unix Epoch

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same.