# jqGrid Doesn't Sort When Showing Epoch Time (since as milliseconds) as Date

Tags: json, jqgrid, epoch

I use jqGrid and my grid definition is like that:

```
...
colNames:['Type','Date','Message','User Name','Host'],
colModel:[{name:'type',index:'type', width:100},
{name:'date',index:'date', sorttype:'date', formatter:'date', 
  formatoptions: {newformat:'d-M-Y'}, width:100},
{name:'log',index:'log', width:200},
{name:'username',index:'username', width:50},
{name:'host',index:'host', width:50}], 
...
```

When I debug my coming data one of the date value (it is Number) is as follows:

```
1322550786997
```

Grid shows it like that:

```
29-Nov-2011
```

Everything is OK till this point. However when I want to sort my date column it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which data type has 1322550786997? Is it `String` or `Number`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that decoding of the Unix (`formatoptions: {srcformat: 'U', newformat: 'd-M-Y'}`) date `1322550786997` get us `19-Dec-43879` and not `29-Nov-2011`. You correct representation of the date will be the string `"\/Date(1322550786997)\/"` instead of the number `1322550786997`.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnixDateFormat.htm):

[image]

**UPDATED**: You can also use the following custom formatter as a workaround

```js
formatter: function (cellval, opts) {
    var date = new Date(cellval);
    opts = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter.date, opts);
    return $.fmatter.util.DateFormat("", date, 'd-M-Y', opts);
}
```

It creates `Date` and then use original `date` formatter to convert it to the format `'d-M-Y'`. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomDateFormater.htm) the demo.

Comment: thanks for your help however I think I miss something. I get time from Java and I think it get date as milliseconds since epoch time.

Comment: @kamaci: If you post the date from Java you should better use ISO 8601 date format (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)). It's standard input format used by jqGrid.

Comment: @kamaci: You can use the workaround which I described in the **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: @Powerlord: I am not sure what you mean. Which from two demos you mean? Moreover the implementation of `srcformat: 'U'` (or `'u'`) is changed since I wrote the answer. What problem you have, what you do and what is not work like expected? The second demo with the custom formatter have to work. Alternatively you can try to use [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin for the date formatting. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245286/315935) which use currency but the date will work in the same way.

Comment: This solution works for 4.3.2, but is there an updated solution for 4.6.0?  It seems like the DateFormat function was removed from the util package.  Perhaps by mistake?  Or was there something to replace it?