# jqgrid datetime formatting

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I have a spring MVC java application and I'm serializing joda DateTime to json.

When I examine the output through the browser the DateTime serialized data looks like this:

```
startDate: 1323147660000
```

I'm not sure which format this data is in.  I've tried many different combinations of srcformat and newformat format options including the following based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212008/in-jqgrid-how-to-format-timestamp-to-dd-mm-yyyy-format):

```
{srcformat:'U', newformat:'m/d/Y'}
```

My hunch is that this is the number of milliseconds since the epoch but I'm not sure how to use it correctly within jqgrid.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: see [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8342427/315935)

Comment: I posted just now [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/support-of-both-u-and-u-php-date-formats/#p25975) with my suggestion how to fix the jqGrid code to support both 'U' and 'u' formats of the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the milliseconds from epoch format was supported out-of-the-box in one of the previous versions of jqGrid. Unfortunately it has been dropped for an unknown reason.

Here is a workaround:

```
{
    name:'startDate',
    label: 'Start date'
    formatter: function(cellValue, options) {
        if(cellValue) {
            return $.fmatter.util.DateFormat(
                '', 
                new Date(+cellValue), 
                'UniversalSortableDateTime', 
                $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter.date, options)
            );
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Note that with custom `formatter` you can parse the date and format it in any way you wish. However I did my best to use built-in jqGrid formatting facilities (see the `UniversalSortableDateTime`?)

Comment: I posted just now [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/support-of-both-u-and-u-php-date-formats/#p25975) with my suggestion how to fix the jqGrid code to support both 'U' and 'u' formats of the date.

Comment: +1 Oleg, thanks. Actually the raw epoch time as a number was working out of the box in previous versions.

Comment: I agree with you. The date formatter from the version 4.1.2 (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L144-149)) worked correctly with 'u' and 'U', but the version 4.2.0 have ["optimized" code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L144-146) which is buggy. I hope that Tony will fix the code.