# Free jqGrid 4.9.0 - Dates format on Safari on MAC

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Testing date format options on all major 4 browsers (Safari, Chrome, IE & Firefox) while working on windows works well.

However, when testing it on MAC machines, the format option failed within Safari (Firefox on MAC works well).

My format option is:

```
gridField.formatter = 'date';
gridField.formatoptions = {};
gridField.formatoptions['srcformat'] = 'U/1000';
gridField.formatoptions['newformat'] = 'm/d/Y H:i:s';
```

Which in Safari (on a MAC only) will yield: NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:Nan:NaN.

Any idea how to overcome the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Which source data you use? One need some test data to reproduce the problem. You wrote about the problem with free jqGrid 4.9.0. Do you verified that the same problem exist in free jqGrid 4.10.0 and in the latest sources from GitHub? You need just change URLs to free jqGrid corresponds to [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit). Could you prepare short demo, which use non-minimized source from GitHub and which can be used to reproduce the problem? I have no Mac, but I will try to test in other environment.

Comment: Sure Oleg,  Here is the Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ngm5rhgp/7/

Comment: If you look at the dates in the demo from ONLY Safari on MAC, they will be looked as NaN

Comment: I don't have any MAC. Could you try the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ngm5rhgp/8/ ?

Comment: Works!  What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following. Free jqGrid uses mostly the same code of `$.jgrid.parseDate` function like jqGrid 4.7. It support the usage `"u"` and `"U"` in the date format in **two different cases**. The first case is the usage of `"u"` and `"U"` **without** any additional format specification (for example, `srcformat:"u"`). It means that jqGrid uses `new Date(inputValue*1000)` to parse the input value. The input value like `1418297439` will be displayed as `12/11/2014 11:30:39` using `newformat: "m/d/Y H:i:s"`. On the other side you have `1418297439000` instead of `1418297439` in the input data and jqGrid don't have some exact formatter for the case.

You use format **`srcformat: "U/1000"`** in your original demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ngm5rhgp/7/. Such format (`"U/1000"`) don't exist at all. The format `"U/1000"` will be interpretet in the same way like `"U/"`, `"U."`, `"U/BlaBla"`, `"U:H:i:s"` or any other which start with `u` following with separator. Because the input data looks like `1418297439000` and **have no additional separators** (`,`, `/`, , `,` and some other) then only the first formatter `U` will be used, but it will be interpreted now as `u` formatter, which means millisecond. The `u` format will be used typically for the format like `12/11/2014 11:30:39,123` where tha last `123` part is the millisecond part of the time.

It seems that Safari on MAC don't allow to create the date as `new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1418297439000)` which uses jqGrid with `1418297439000` as input data and `srcformat: "U/1000"`.

What I suggest you to do is **modifying the input data and the usage of `srcformat: "u"` format**. One need to enumerate all items of input data and to devide `start_time` and `end_time` properties to `100`. I used in my demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ngm5rhgp/8/ the code

```
var mydata = [{...},{...}... {...}], n = mydata.length, item, i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    item = mydata[i];
    item.start_time = Math.floor(item.start_time / 1000);
    item.end_time = Math.floor(item.end_time / 1000);
}
```

and have replaces `srcformat: "U/1000"` to `srcformat: "u"`. If you have not `"local"` value of `datatype` than you can modify the data inside of `beforeProcessing` callback.

**UPDATED**: To simplify processing of the time in milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT), like `1418297439000`, I introduced in free jqGrid **new format option: `srcformat: "u1000"`**. The new demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ngm5rhgp/9/
 uses **unmodified** input data and just use `srcformat: "u1000"` instead of `srcformat: "U/1000"`. To use it one have to use the latest free jqGrid from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).