# jqgrid: issue with beforeProcessing and loadonce

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using Guriddo jqGrid 5.2.1.  I've defined a `jsonReader` to handle the non-standard format of the data being returned by the URL:

```
jsonReader : {
            root:"payload.rows",
            page: "payload.page",  // the current page
            total: "payload.total",  // the total # of pages
            records: "payload.records"  // the total # of records
        },
```

The grid also has `loadonce` set to `true`, so that all of the data is loaded once.  This makes it possible for me to let the grid handle sorting instead of requesting sorted data from the server.  One of the input fields in the rows is a date represented in milliseconds.  I defined a `beforeProcessing` function to handle converting the date in each row to be a value that can be formatted properly:

```
beforeProcessing: function (data) {

            for(var i = 0; i < data.payload.rows.length; i++) {
                var d = new Date(data.payload.rows[i].ihw);
                data.payload.rows[i].ihw = d;
            }

        },
```

This worked fine when the data is initially retrieved.  However, I noticed that `beforeProcessing` is called whenever I click on a column to sort, even though `loadonce` is set to `true`.  I can change the code to handle formatting the date using a `formatter` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335652/converting-the-milliseconds-to-date-format-for-jqgrid).  However, I have other data manipulation needs where, for example, I'd like add a new field to each row that is a concatenation of three other fields in the row.  When `jsonReader` is used, the incoming data appears to be transformed into the standard jqgrid format, so that the next time `beforeProcessing` is executed (upon a sort, for example), the `beforeProcessing` code errors because the data is now in a different format than before.  Is there an event I can use that only runs once, after the data is initially retrieved from the server?  Or do I need to set a JavaScrpt variable in `beforeProcessing` that indicates that the data has been processed once, and skip processing in subsequent calls?

Comment: It seems that the problem is specific for commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you use. Neither [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) nor old jqGrid (in versions <=4.7) should has the problem.

Comment: If you want to continue to use commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS then I'd recommend you to insert `if (this.p.datatype === "json") {/*the for loop*/}` in the code of `beforeProcessing`. It allows you to make some modifications of the data returned from *the server* before the data will be processed by jqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

The old code does not take in account beforeProcessing event when the datatype was local - that was the reason to fix this bug and add beforeProcessing to the all datatypes.

Since the option *loadonce* is set to true you datatype is changed from json to local, but to the beforeProcessing is passed different data as you mentioned.

One possible solution is to set a flag to execute this code only once or set the same event to null in the event

```
beforeProcessing: function (data) {

        for(var i = 0; i < data.payload.rows.length; i++) {
            var d = new Date(data.payload.rows[i].ihw);
            data.payload.rows[i].ihw = d;
        }
        this.p.beforeProcessing = null;

    },
```